# Defining an RDLC chart axis with an aggregate function

Tags: rdlc

The autoaxis for one of my embedded charts isn't behaving well, sometimes only showing one other major value besides top and bottom. So I thought I'd set my own boundaries, which seemed pretty easy given that one of the columns on the chart is always going to be larger than any of the others.

```
<Maximum>=(((Max(Fields!Entered.Value, "Chart1") + 10) \ 50) + 1) * 50</Maximum>
```

(the other columns detail what happened to the things that entered this process)

Round up to the nearest 50 with a little overage to put the label on top. Then I can put the intervals at this divided by 5 and I'm gold.

Except I'm not gold. The chart groups records by date and the individual bars are Sum(Fields!Entered.Value) et cetera, so it's drastically underscaling when multiple batches get processed on a single date. But hey, it groups records by date, I can use that:

```
<ChartCategoryHierarchy>
  <ChartMembers>
    <ChartMember>
      <Group Name="Chart1_CategoryGroup">
        <GroupExpressions>
          <GroupExpression>=Fields!Date.Value</GroupExpression>
        </GroupExpressions>
      </Group>
    </ChartMember>
  </ChartMembers>
</ChartCategoryHierarchy>
```

as:

```
<Maximum>=(((Max(Fields!Entered.Value, "Chart1_CategoryGroup") + 10) \ 50) + 1) * 50</Maximum>
```

and it'll aggregate over the group just fine. Right?

> The ValueAxis_Primary.Maximum expression for the chart 'Chart1' has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function.  The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset.

Nope! It works just fine for "Chart1" but not for "Chart1_CategoryGroup"!

So, uh:

- what scope are the axis calculations operating in, 'cause it ain't the category scope?
- is there some way to provide them an aggregate scope that groups the data by date so they can do their calculations proper?

Answer (score 0):

## You Have To Nest The Scope

A little extra work gave me this insight:

`Max(Fields!Entered.Value, "Chart1_CategoryGroup")` returns the maximum of the entered fields **within one single category group**, which is not the level the Y axis is concerned with. What you're interested in is the maximum value of the **summed calculation** (within a group) **for the whole chart**, so specify the scopes to do that:

```
<Maximum>
  =(((Max(
    Sum(Fields!Entered.Value, "Chart1_CategoryGroup")
  , "Chart1") + 10) \ 50) + 1) * 50
</Maximum>
```